# client side references to objects using webapi and angularJs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am sure that there is a simple way to do this, but i just dont know about it.

I have an angularJs clientside application (using .net webapi and entity framework on the server) that uses objects with a parent/child relationship.  These objects can be created in my angularJs application, and have an id property of `null` on the client.  When i send the object to the web api, that id is populated.

So for example, i could send this to my server

```
main: {
    name: 'jim',
    children: [
        { id: null, name: 'dave' },
        { id: null, name: 'bob' }
    ]
}
```

This works fine in a parent/child relationship.  On my server, this would create c# models like below, and using AutoMapper, i can set the children to reference its parent object.

```
public MainModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public ChildModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My autoMapper file would say something like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Main, MainModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<MainModel, Main>()
    .AfterMap((s, d) => {
        foreach (var item in d.Children) 
            item.Main = d;
    });
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, ChildModel>().ReverseMap();
```

However, if i introduce another object, that isnt in a child collection, my code is getting confused, because multiple objects can have an id = 0.  For example

```
main: {
    name: 'jim',
    children: [
        { id: 0, name: 'dave' },
        { id: 0, name: 'bob' }
    ],
    bestChildId: 0  // which child is this pointing too?
}
```

As you can see bestChildId, is not referencing a child object, but because they both have an id of 0, it doesnt know which one.

What is the best way to go about this?  Is there a framework that i should be using with angular that overcomes this?  Or do i have to implement referencing on the client, and link it all up on the server.  Something like this

```
main: {
    name: 'jim',
    children: [
        { id: 0, name: 'dave' },
        { id: 0, name: 'bob' }
    ],
    bestChildId: 0,  // this could point to an id, and will be downloaded from server upon fetch
    bestChild: {  // use this property on the client, only when id equals 0
        id: 0, name: 'dave'
    }
}
```

Comment: In your AngularJS app, what does your request look like? Are you using $http, $resource, Restangular or some other service? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: I am using $http.  The request uses Id properties, which is fine when you fetch an object, because all the items exist and have unique ids.  Its posting the object to the webApi (which uses Ids) that causes the problem

Comment: This doesn't sound like an Angular problem. $http simply makes the request to your API and returns a promise. Assuming your API returns the object with IDs assigned on POST, you need to then modify your object in Angular, using the promise.then(successHandler, errorHandler) syntax. Your successHandler method is where you would glean the IDs from the $http response object.

Comment: Yeah currently, i do not download the "related" objects, just pointers to the IDs, and the same on upload.  I think i need to update my webApi, to accept objects as well, much like entity framework

Comment: Hey bro, did you solve this issue ? 
I have the same problem and I can't find the answe ?

Comment: Nope, i have left it for the moment, but i think i will change the properties on clientside to have a clientId.  That way i can relink the objects back up on the clientId which will always be unique when i get to the server.  You got any other ideas?